# Dagger 2.26 field injection into application failed

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger

When I try to inject app crashing with lateinit property ... has not been initialized exception. I understand I have to inject my app into graph, but I do not succeed in that. What is the best way to do this?

```
class App : Application() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var localeManager: Lazy<LocaleManager>

    val appComponent: AppComponent by lazy {
        DaggerAppComponent.factory().create(applicationContext)
    }

    override fun attachBaseContext(base: Context) {
        super.attachBaseContext(localeManager.get().setLocale(base))
    }

    override fun onConfigurationChanged(newConfig: Configuration) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig)
        localeManager.get().setLocale(this)
    }
}

@Singleton
@Component(modules = [NetworkModule::class, AppSubcomponents::class])
interface AppComponent {
    @Component.Factory
    interface Factory {
        fun create(@BindsInstance context: Context): AppComponent
    }

    fun registrationComponent(): RegistrationComponent.Factory
    fun lobbyComponent(): PropertyComponent.Factory
    fun supplierComponent(): SupplierComponent.Factory
    fun notificationComponent(): NotificationComponent.Factory
    fun serviceComponent(): ServiceComponent.Factory
    fun settingsComponent() : SettingsComponent.Factory
    fun cardComponent() : CardComponent.Factory

    fun inject(activity: MainActivity)

}

class LocaleManager @Inject constructor(val storage: UserStorage) {
   //some code 
}
```

Comment: You never inject `App` so `localeManager` isn't initialized.

Comment: val appComponent: AppComponent by lazy {
        DaggerAppComponent.factory().create(applicationContext).apply { 
                    inject(this@App) }
        }.

Comment: I tried to do this, but this did not solve the problem

Comment: It didn't work because that way injection happens when you access `appComponent` and you never accessed `appComponent`. You accessed `localeManager`. If you called `appComponent.inject(this)` in `onCreate`, then it would work.

Comment: override fun onCreate() {
        appComponent.inject(this)
        super.onCreate()
    }

Comment: this still not working(

Comment: `attachBaseContext` is the first thing to run in an app. This is going to be a problem because you need attached context for instantiating `appComponent`. But you also want `appComponent` ready inside `attachBaseContext`.

Comment: You won't have access to the graph inside `attachBaseContext`. Can you postpone whatever `localeManager` does to `onCreate`?